# plotting in octave syntax

Tags: machine-learning, octave

```
pos = find(y==1);
neg = find(y==0);

plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), "k+", "LineWidth", 2, 'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), "ko", "MarkerFaceColor", 'y', 'MarkerSize', 7);
```

I understand that find function gives us the index of the data where y==1 and y==0. But I am not sure what X(pos,1) and X(pos,2) do in the function below. Can someone explain how this plot function works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pos` and `neg` are vectors with indices where the condition `y==1` (respectively y==0) is fulfiled. `y` seems to be a vector with length n, `X` seems to be a nx2 Matrix. `X(pos,1)` are all elements of the first column of `X` at rows where the condition `y==1` is met.

```
y = [ 2 3 1 4 0 1 2 6 0 4]
X = [55 19;54 96;19 85;74 81;94 34;82 80;79 92;57 36;70 81;69 4]
X(find(y==1), 1)
```

which gives

```
ans =
   19
   82
```

Note that find isn't needed here,

```
X(y==1, 1)
```

would be sufficient

Comment: Andy, what is the meaning of 'k+' and 'ko' here, and where in documentation can I find these.

Comment: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Advanced-Plotting.html#Advanced-Plotting they are color and marker style settings. In your case black and cross respectively a circle

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, but still I can't find the mention of 'k+' and 'ko' in the documentation

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli There is a list with all linestyles, colors and markerstyles here https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html#Two_002dDimensional-Plots

Comment: @Andy  In plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), "ko", "MarkerFaceColor", 'y', 'MarkerSize', 7);    
what does 'y' doing here for as y is not a fixed value? –

Comment: @AminurRahmanAshik see the link above. 'y' ist the short colorcode for 'yellow'

Answer (score 0):

Here X is nx2 matix and pos is a m vector having indexes where y==1 in the matrix X.
As X(pos,1) is m x 1 matrix with values of 1st row of matrix X where x==1, same is the case of X(pos,2).

Plotting a graph with
   `plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), "k+", "LineWidth", 2, 'MarkerSize', 7);`

will give you a graph with '+'points having x coordinate X(pos,1) [values of 1st row of matrix X where x==1] and y coordinate X(pos,2) [values of 2st row of matrix X where x==1].

Similarly with `plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), "ko", "MarkerFaceColor", 'y', 'MarkerSize', 7);`
will give you a graph with yellow dots having x coordinate X(neg,1) [values of 1st row of matrix X where x==0] and y coordinate X(neg,2) [values of 2st row of matrix X where x==0].

You can also directly use `y==1` instead of `pos`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
pos = find(y == 1); neg = find(y == 0);
% Plot Examples
plot(X(pos, 1), X(pos, 2), 'k+','LineWidth', 2,'MarkerSize', 7);
plot(X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2), 'ko', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'y', 'MarkerSize', 7);
```

Answer: In simple word, X(pos, 1) stores all the values of first column of X where y == 1
and X(pos, 2) store all the values of second column of X where y == 1.
Similarly it will happens to X(neg, 1), X(neg, 2) where X stores the values of first, Second Columns of X respectively where y == 0.
Now I'm including some output here to better understanding.
here is my dataset.

> 34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
>
> 61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
>
> 30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
>
> 35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
>
> 60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
>
> 79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1

[image: Changing in code can see with yellow colored lines.]

[image: output]

[See the values of X(pos, 1) "first column of X where y == 1 ", X(pos, 2) Second column of X where y == 1 " , X(neg, 1) first column of X where y == 0 " and X(neg, 2) Second column of X where y == 0 "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I301o.png)

You can that X(pos, 2) plot over X(pos, 1), similarly X(neg, 2) plot over X(neg, 1)